# How to check ferrite beads?

Tags: inductor, inductance, ferrite-bead, inductance-measurement

I faced with a problem of checking ferrite bead with parameters:

[image]

The measurements for two reels of this component have difference in Resistance and inductance:

> Reel 1: Resistance: 170 mOhm, Inductance: 2.5 uH (10kHz)
>
> Reel 2: Resistance: 460 mOhm, Inductance: 9.9 uH (10kHz)

Can You assist with next questions:

1. Why there are such difference in **Resistance** and **Inductance** between two components from different reels? Does this difference matter?
2. Why in spec don’t specified inductance?
3. Why on Characteristic Curve no value of impedance 1000 Ohm? Because I guess that curve for **Z** should be with Impedance value near 1000 Ohm.

[image: Characteristic Curve]

Comment: Do you understand \$Pd=ESR*I^2\$ and saturation effects with Idc and resulting error at 10kHz with 0Adc

Comment: No, I don't understand. Can you explain what you mean?

Comment: you dont understand anything about power loss, saturation and inductance>?

Comment: I don't understand about power loss and saturation.

Comment: inductors raised impedance by storing energy, Resistors raise impedance by dissipating energy.  electronics 101

Comment: @Tony Stewart older than dirt, Can you also said for which parameter specified Tolerance ? I guess that it is only for Impedance.

Comment: the purpose of ferrite is to raise RF impedance to reduce noise current.  How they achieve that is up to supplier. Do you care?  Their spec has wide tolerances of 25% because noise spans many decades so this is fine to give a simple test critieria at 100MHz . If you prefer an inductor then use them to create a filter,.

Answer (score 2):

> In specification defined only maximum value of DCR: 550 mOhm. So, does
>   the difference in DCR matter?

That totally depends on your target circuit and what it maximum DCR it can live with to function/perform to expectations.

> Why in spec don’t specified inductance and on Characteristic Curve no
>   value of impedance 1000 Ohm?

Sure it's there - see the "X" curve - that is the inductive reactance versus frequency.

> Also why can exist such difference between two components from
>   different reels?

The spec says maximum DCR of 0.55 ohms so why shouldn't you expect a typical DCR range from 0.17 to 0.46 ohms? If you looked at a MOSFET spec for its on-resistance I bet you could get a up to a 3 to 1 variation between min and max.

Comment: I had misconception about DCR. Actually I mean that I measured Resistance and Inductance of two components. And there were difference in that parameters. So I don't know is it normal? And why for ferrite bead no Inductance value?

Comment: Sure it's got an inductance value - look at the graph as I said in my answer - X is inductive reactance.

Comment: Now I understand. So am I right to understand that in such case one of my component is bad, due to differences in R and L?

Comment: @KMM I can't tell you if you have a bad component - which parameter is outside the limits specified in the data sheet?

Comment: Okay. One more question, Why the curve for Z do not reach value 1000 Ohm on the graph?

Comment: I don't know  - if the data sheet doesn't explain this maybe it's time to find a part that has unambiguous performance specifications in the data sheet. That would worry me and I would disregard it and find a part whose data sheet I could trust. Maybe they test it at 100 MHz with some capacitance assumed to be in parallel?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77748/discussion-between-kmm-and-andy-aka).

Comment: I’ve said all that I can say and it’s late in England.

Answer (score 1):

Ferrite Beads often have complex equivalent circuits.

So which L would you like to see ? ( neither )

[image]

\$Z(f)=\sqrt{R^2+X^2(f)}\$

Suppliers often have several material choices to meet one part number specification by different recipes.
[image]
You can easily see the primary inductance impedance here.
[image]

Your unwritten question is how do you approve these parts?

Answer: Write better specs with acceptance criteria of Z(f) vs I vs f.
Then the acceptance criteria is simple.

Comment: I don't know how to approve these parts. I see only difference in R and L and don't know is it normal for ferrite bead. Does it mean that one part is bad? Also can you explain how to read this chart?

Comment: L is shown for 2uH rises to 1kHZ at 10MHz but it must have shunt R also to absorb energy. Do you know anything about passive parts?